# How to properly extend a module in Rails 6 using Zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeitwerk

I'm in process of switching from `classic` autoloader to `zeitwerk`. And I've faced this problem:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant SomeHelper::Forms
```

I have a helper module `SomeHelper` in `app/helpers/some_helper.rb` which contains this code

```
module SomeHelper
  extend Forms::DateTimePickerHelper
    ...rest code....
```

The `Forms::DateTimePickerHelper` module is located in `app/helpers/forms/date_time_picker_helper.rb`

My question is: how to correct the file structure or module names to make Zeitwerk good?

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause, in `config/application.rb` these lines were added

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/helpers')
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/helpers/forms')
```

removing them solved the issue. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This code was never actually needed. In both Zeitwerk and Classic every subdirectory  of app is an autoloading root so it would look for the constant in `app/**/forms/some_helper.rb` anyways.